# cant get scroll function to show/hide header?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Cant get this function to hide header on scroll down and reappear on scroll up?

```js
       $(function(){
    var lastScrollTop = 0, delta = 5;
    $(window).scroll(function(event){
       var st = $(this).scrollTop();
       if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
          return;
       if (st > lastScrollTop){
           // downscroll code
           $('.wrapper').slideUp('230');
       } else {
          // upscroll code
          $('.wrapper').slideDown('230');
       }
       lastScrollTop = st;
    });
});
```

```css
/* ---- ALL QUERIES ---- */

/* ---- Wrapper ---- */

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    position: fixed;
    height: 80px;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #eee;
                
}

/* ---- Wrapper End --- */

/* ---- Logo ---- */

.logo-header {
    width: 27.5%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 80px;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: 2.5%;        
}

.logo-header img {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
}

/* ---- Logo End --- */

/* ---- Hamburger ---- */

.responsive-hide {
        width: 50%;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        padding-right: 2.5%;
    }
    
.toggle-nav {
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        align-items: center;
        height: 80px;
        
        
    }
    
#hamburger {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        width: 36px;
        height: 20px;
        color: #949494;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
        -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
        transition: .5s ease-in-out;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
#hamburger span {
        color: #949494;
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        height: 2px;
        width: 100%;
        background: #949494;
        border-radius: 2px;
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
        -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
        transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    }
    
#hamburger span:nth-child(1) {
        top: 0px;
    }

#hamburger span:nth-child(2) {
        top: 8px;
    }

#hamburger span:nth-child(3) {
        top: 16px;
    }
    
#hamburger.open span:nth-child(1) {
        top: 9px;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
        transform: rotate(135deg);
    }

#hamburger.open span:nth-child(2) {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
        transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;    
    }

#hamburger.open span:nth-child(3) {
        top: 5px;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
        transform: rotate(-135deg);
    }
    
#hamburger:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
        color: #555555;
    }

/* ---- Hamburger End --- */

/* ---- Responsive Hide Nav ---- */

.responsive-nav {
        position: absolute;
        top: 60px;
        right: 0;
        display: block;
        font-size: 2.4rem;
        font-weight: 400;
        width: 50vw;
        height: 100vh;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        transform: translateX( 100% );
        transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
        
    }
    
.responsive-nav2 {
        margin: 0;
        
    }
    
.reveal {
        transform: translateX( 0 );
          
    }
    
.responsive-nav ul {
        display: block;
        padding-left: 0px !important;
        font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
        font-size: 2rem;
        list-style: none;
                
   
    }
    
.responsive-nav li {
        display: block;
        padding: 0;
        position: relative;    
    }
    
.responsive-nav a:hover {
        color: #555555;
    }
    
.responsive-nav li:first-child {
        display: block;
        padding-top: 10px;
        position: relative;
        
    }
    
.responsive-nav a {
        display: block;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #949494;
        position: relative;   
    }

/* ---- Responsive Hide Nav End --- */

/* ---- Site Nav ---- */

.site-nav {
    width: 50%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    font-size: 2.4rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    padding-right: 2.5%;
    
        
}

.site-nav ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    list-style: none;
    align-items: center;
    
    
}

.site-nav ul:before, .site-nav ul:after { content: ""; display: table; }
.site-nav ul:after { clear: both; }
.site-nav ul { *zoom: 1; }

.site-nav ul li  {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #949494;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 1.6rem;
    
    
}
.site-nav ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #949494;
    text-decoration: none;
    
    
}
.site-nav ul li a:hover {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #555555;
    text-decoration: none;
    
}
li.current-menu-item a {
    color: #555555 !important;
    text-decoration: none;
    
}

/* ---- Site Nav End --- */

/* ---- Socials Nav ---- */

.socials {
        width: 20%;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        align-items: center;
        border-left: 2px solid #eee;
        padding: 0 2.5% 0 2.5%;
        
        
}

.socials ul li {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;

}

.socials ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-around;

}

.socials li img {
    max-height: 40px;
}

/* ---- Socials Nav End --- */

@media only screen and (max-width: 450px) {
    
/* ---- Wrapper ---- */

    .wrapper {
        height: 60px;
    }

/* ---- Wrapper End --- */

/* ---- Logo ---- */

    .logo-header {
        height: 60px;
        width:47.5% 
    }

    .logo-header img {
        height: 40px;
        width: 40px;
    }

/* ---- Logo End --- */

/* ---- Hamburger ---- */

    .responsive-hide {
        width: 50%;
    }
    
    .toggle-nav {
        height: 60px;
    }
    

/* ---- Hamburger End --- */

    .socials {
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 1.5% 25% 1.5% 25%;
        background: #fff;
        transform: translateY( 0 );
        transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
        
    }
    
    .socialshide {
        transform: translateY( 100% );
    }

    .socials ul li {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;

    }

    .socials ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-around;

    }

    .socials li img {
    max-height: 35px;
    }

/* ---- Responsive Hide Nav ---- */

.responsive-nav {
        position: fixed;
        top: 125px;
        font-size: 2.4rem;
        width: 100%;
        height: 66vh;
        min-height: 100vh;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        transform: translateY( 100% );
        transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
        border-top: solid 1px #eee;
        
        
        
    }
    
    .responsive-nav li:first-child {
        display: block;
        padding-top: 10px;
        position: relative;
        
    }
    
    .responsive-nav2 {
        margin: 0;
        
    }
    
    .reveal {
        transform: translateY( 0 );
          
    }

/* ---- Responsive Hide Nav End --- */
    
/* ---- Site Nav ---- */

    .site-nav {
            display: none;
    }

/* ---- Site Nav End --- */

/* ---- Socials Nav ---- */

/* ---- Socials Nav End --- */

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 451px) and (max-width: 768px) {
    
/* ---- Wrapper ---- */

    .wrapper {
        height: 60px;
    }

/* ---- Wrapper End --- */

/* ---- Logo ---- */

    .logo-header {
        height: 60px;
            
    }

    .logo-header img {
        height: 40px;
        width: 40px;
    }

/* ---- Logo End --- */

/* ---- Hamburger ---- */

    .responsive-hide {
        width: 45%;
    }
    
    .toggle-nav {
        height: 60px;
    }

/* ---- Hamburger End --- */

/* ---- Responsive Hide Nav ---- */

/* ---- Responsive Hide Nav End --- */

/* ---- Site Nav ---- */

    .site-nav {
        display: none;
    }

/* ---- Site Nav End --- */

/* ---- Socials Nav ---- */

    .socials {
        width: 25%;
        justify-content: space-around;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    .socials ul {
        padding: 0 5%;
    }
    
    .socials ul li {
        margin: auto 2.5%;
                
    }

    .socials li img {
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 35px;
    }

}
    
/* ---- Socials Nav End --- */
    


@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 899px) {

/* ---- Wrapper ---- */

    .wrapper {
        height: 70px;
    }

/* ---- Wrapper End --- */

/* ---- Logo ---- */

    .logo-header {
        height: 70px;
           
    }

    .logo-header img {
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
    }

/* ---- Logo End --- */

/* ---- Hamburger ---- */

    .responsive-hide {
        display: none;    
    }

/* ---- Hamburger End --- */

/* ---- Responsive Hide Nav ---- */

    .responsive-nav {
        display: none;
        }

    .responsive-nav ul {
        display: none;
        }

    .responsive-nav li {
        display: none;
        }

/* ---- Responsive Hide Nav End --- */

/* ---- Site Nav ---- */

    .site-nav {
        font-size: 2rem;
        padding-right: 3.5%;
    }

/* ---- Site Nav End --- */

/* ---- Socials Nav ---- */

    .socials {
        justify-content: space-around;
        padding: 0 1.5% 0 1.5%;
        
        
    }

    .socials ul li {
        height: 35px;
        width: 35px;
        
    }

    .socials li img {
        max-height: 35px;
    }

/* ---- Socials Nav End --- */
    
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    
/* ---- Wrapper ---- */

/* ---- Wrapper End --- */

/* ---- Logo ---- */

/* ---- Logo End --- */

/* ---- Hamburger ---- */

    .responsive-hide {
        display: none;    
    }

/* ---- Hamburger End --- */

/* ---- Responsive Hide Nav ---- */

    .responsive-nav {
        display: none;
        }

    .responsive-nav ul {
        display: none;
        }

    .responsive-nav li {
        display: none;
        }

/* ---- Responsive Hide Nav End --- */

/* ---- Site Nav ---- */

/* ---- Site Nav End --- */

/* ---- Socials Nav ---- */

/* ---- Socials Nav End --- */
    
}
```

```html
<header class="wrapper">
                            
                            <div class="logo-header">
                                <img src= "http://testsiteclash.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/luke-logo-layers-copy.png">
                            </div>
                            
                            <!-- responsive nav -->
                            <div class="responsive-hide">
                                <div class="toggle-nav">
                                    <div id="hamburger">
                                        <span></span>
                                        <span></span>
                                        <span></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <nav>
                                    <ul id="responsive-nav2" class="responsive-nav"><li id="menu-item-32" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-5 current_page_item menu-item-32"><a href="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-31" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-31"><a href="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/about">About</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-30" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-30"><a href="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/gallery">Gallery</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-29" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-29"><a href="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>                                </nav>
                            </div>
                            <!-- responsive nav -->
                            
                            <!-- nav -->
                            <nav class="site-nav">
                                <ul><li id="menu-item-9" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-9"><a href="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-10" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-10"><a href="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/about">About</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-47" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-47"><a href="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/blog">Blog</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-18" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-18"><a href="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>                            </nav>
                            <!-- /nav -->
                            
                                                       
                            <div class="socials">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/facebook-icon.png" id="facebook" onmouseover="newPicture()" onmouseout="oldPicture()"/></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/insta-icon.png" id="instagram" onmouseover="newPicture1()" onmouseout="oldPicture1()"/></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/twitter-icon.png" id="twitter" onmouseover="newPicture2()" onmouseout="oldPicture2()"/></a></li>
                                    <!--<li><a href="#"><img src="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/pinterest-icon.png" id="pinterest" onmouseover="newPicture3()" onmouseout="oldPicture3()"/></a></li>-->
                                </ul>
                            </div>

     

   </header>
   <!-- /header -->
```

the header has a class of wrapper and has a fixed position? What am i doing wrong? There was too much css and html for the snippet so thought start with the function and see where that is going wrong? The function is in my jqueryheader.js file that is loading as an add-action. Thanks

Comment: can you show the html for it as well and include a working example?

Comment: best place to view a working example is testsiteclash.co.uk, i have added html for the header

Comment: Please review how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can add a boolean variable, something like a checker for the animation. Please try this:

```js
var checker = false;

$(document).scroll(function() {
  var lastScrollTop = 0,
    delta = 5;
  $(window).scroll(function(event) {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (st > lastScrollTop) {
      // downscroll code
      if (checker == false) {
        $('.wrapper').slideUp('230');
        checker = true;
      }
    } else {
      // upscroll code
      $('.wrapper').slideDown('230');
      checker = false;
    }

  });
});
```

```css
/* ---- ALL QUERIES ---- */


/* ---- Wrapper ---- */

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  position: fixed;
  height: 80px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #eee;
  background: #f00;
}


/* ---- Wrapper End --- */


/* ---- Logo ---- */

.logo-header {
  width: 27.5%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 80px;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 2.5%;
}

.logo-header img {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
}


/* ---- Logo End --- */


/* ---- Hamburger ---- */

.responsive-hide {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding-right: 2.5%;
}

.toggle-nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  height: 80px;
}

#hamburger {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 36px;
  height: 20px;
  color: #949494;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#hamburger span {
  color: #949494;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #949494;
  border-radius: 2px;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}

#hamburger span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
}

#hamburger span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 8px;
}

#hamburger span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 16px;
}

#hamburger.open span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 9px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

#hamburger.open span:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

#hamburger.open span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 5px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

#hamburger:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #555555;
}


/* ---- Hamburger End --- */


/* ---- Responsive Hide Nav ---- */

.responsive-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  transform: translateX( 100%);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.responsive-nav2 {
  margin: 0;
}

.reveal {
  transform: translateX( 0);
}

.responsive-nav ul {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 0px !important;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 2rem;
  list-style: none;
}

.responsive-nav li {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.responsive-nav a:hover {
  color: #555555;
}

.responsive-nav li:first-child {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.responsive-nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #949494;
  position: relative;
}


/* ---- Responsive Hide Nav End --- */


/* ---- Site Nav ---- */

.site-nav {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding-right: 2.5%;
}

.site-nav ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
  align-items: center;
}

.site-nav ul:before,
.site-nav ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.site-nav ul:after {
  clear: both;
}

.site-nav ul {
  *zoom: 1;
}

.site-nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #949494;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-left: 1.6rem;
}

.site-nav ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #949494;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.site-nav ul li a:hover {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #555555;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li.current-menu-item a {
  color: #555555 !important;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* ---- Site Nav End --- */


/* ---- Socials Nav ---- */

.socials {
  width: 20%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  border-left: 2px solid #eee;
  padding: 0 2.5% 0 2.5%;
}

.socials ul li {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}

.socials ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.socials li img {
  max-height: 40px;
}


/* ---- Socials Nav End --- */

@media only screen and (max-width: 450px) {
  /* ---- Wrapper ---- */
  .wrapper {
    height: 60px;
  }
  /* ---- Wrapper End --- */
  /* ---- Logo ---- */
  .logo-header {
    height: 60px;
    width: 47.5%
  }
  .logo-header img {
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
  }
  /* ---- Logo End --- */
  /* ---- Hamburger ---- */
  .responsive-hide {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .toggle-nav {
    height: 60px;
  }
  /* ---- Hamburger End --- */
  .socials {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 1.5% 25% 1.5% 25%;
    background: #fff;
    transform: translateY( 0);
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  }
  .socialshide {
    transform: translateY( 100%);
  }
  .socials ul li {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
  }
  .socials ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
  .socials li img {
    max-height: 35px;
  }
  /* ---- Responsive Hide Nav ---- */
  .responsive-nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 125px;
    font-size: 2.4rem;
    width: 100%;
    height: 66vh;
    min-height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    transform: translateY( 100%);
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
    border-top: solid 1px #eee;
  }
  .responsive-nav li:first-child {
    display: block;
    padding-top: 10px;
    position: relative;
  }
  .responsive-nav2 {
    margin: 0;
  }
  .reveal {
    transform: translateY( 0);
  }
  /* ---- Responsive Hide Nav End --- */
  /* ---- Site Nav ---- */
  .site-nav {
    display: none;
  }
  /* ---- Site Nav End --- */
  /* ---- Socials Nav ---- */
  /* ---- Socials Nav End --- */
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 451px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  /* ---- Wrapper ---- */
  .wrapper {
    height: 60px;
  }
  /* ---- Wrapper End --- */
  /* ---- Logo ---- */
  .logo-header {
    height: 60px;
  }
  .logo-header img {
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
  }
  /* ---- Logo End --- */
  /* ---- Hamburger ---- */
  .responsive-hide {
    width: 45%;
  }
  .toggle-nav {
    height: 60px;
  }
  /* ---- Hamburger End --- */
  /* ---- Responsive Hide Nav ---- */
  /* ---- Responsive Hide Nav End --- */
  /* ---- Site Nav ---- */
  .site-nav {
    display: none;
  }
  /* ---- Site Nav End --- */
  /* ---- Socials Nav ---- */
  .socials {
    width: 25%;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .socials ul {
    padding: 0 5%;
  }
  .socials ul li {
    margin: auto 2.5%;
  }
  .socials li img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 35px;
  }
}


/* ---- Socials Nav End --- */

@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 899px) {
  /* ---- Wrapper ---- */
  .wrapper {
    height: 70px;
  }
  /* ---- Wrapper End --- */
  /* ---- Logo ---- */
  .logo-header {
    height: 70px;
  }
  .logo-header img {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
  }
  /* ---- Logo End --- */
  /* ---- Hamburger ---- */
  .responsive-hide {
    display: none;
  }
  /* ---- Hamburger End --- */
  /* ---- Responsive Hide Nav ---- */
  .responsive-nav {
    display: none;
  }
  .responsive-nav ul {
    display: none;
  }
  .responsive-nav li {
    display: none;
  }
  /* ---- Responsive Hide Nav End --- */
  /* ---- Site Nav ---- */
  .site-nav {
    font-size: 2rem;
    padding-right: 3.5%;
  }
  /* ---- Site Nav End --- */
  /* ---- Socials Nav ---- */
  .socials {
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding: 0 1.5% 0 1.5%;
  }
  .socials ul li {
    height: 35px;
    width: 35px;
  }
  .socials li img {
    max-height: 35px;
  }
  /* ---- Socials Nav End --- */
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  /* ---- Wrapper ---- */
  /* ---- Wrapper End --- */
  /* ---- Logo ---- */
  /* ---- Logo End --- */
  /* ---- Hamburger ---- */
  .responsive-hide {
    display: none;
  }
  /* ---- Hamburger End --- */
  /* ---- Responsive Hide Nav ---- */
  .responsive-nav {
    display: none;
  }
  .responsive-nav ul {
    display: none;
  }
  .responsive-nav li {
    display: none;
  }
  /* ---- Responsive Hide Nav End --- */
  /* ---- Site Nav ---- */
  /* ---- Site Nav End --- */
  /* ---- Socials Nav ---- */
  /* ---- Socials Nav End --- */
}

.content {
  background: #adadad;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="wrapper">

  <div class="logo-header">
    <img src="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/luke-logo-layers-copy.png">
  </div>

  <!-- responsive nav -->
  <div class="responsive-hide">
    <div class="toggle-nav">
      <div id="hamburger">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul id="responsive-nav2" class="responsive-nav">
        <li id="menu-item-32" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-5 current_page_item menu-item-32"><a href="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/">Home</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-31" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-31"><a href="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/about">About</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-30" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-30"><a href="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/gallery">Gallery</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-29" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-29"><a href="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <!-- responsive nav -->

  <!-- nav -->
  <nav class="site-nav">
    <ul>
      <li id="menu-item-9" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-9"><a href="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/">Home</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-10" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-10"><a href="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/about">About</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-47" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-47"><a href="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/blog">Blog</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-18" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-18"><a href="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <!-- /nav -->


  <div class="socials">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/facebook-icon.png" id="facebook" onmouseover="newPicture()" onmouseout="oldPicture()" /></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/insta-icon.png" id="instagram" onmouseover="newPicture1()" onmouseout="oldPicture1()" /></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/twitter-icon.png" id="twitter" onmouseover="newPicture2()" onmouseout="oldPicture2()" /></a>
      </li>
      <!--<li><a href="#"><img src="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/pinterest-icon.png" id="pinterest" onmouseover="newPicture3()" onmouseout="oldPicture3()"/></a></li>-->
    </ul>
  </div>



</header>
<!-- /header -->
<div class='content'></div>
```

Comment: sorry cant get it to work? Why have you added a div class of content? is that the only thing I am missing to make it work as that is not in my original html and how will that affect my class of container where my content is being brought in? Thanks

Comment: or should i move my html of <div class ="container"> after the header as this is where my content is being brought in?

Comment: @PaulStephenDavis, I've added the `.container` element just for testing, because I couldn't scroll down to test it. I've also updated my answer a bit with a condition based on the `checker` variable. I hope that now is working as you need. I've also removed the `if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)` as you didn't need that

Comment: I placed that js in but it still isnt showing or hiding header?

Comment: @PaulStephenDavis, please check the console for errors.

Comment: $(document).scroll(function() {  Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

Comment: @lonut when i change the beginnning of the function to this jQuery(document).scroll(function() { it shows no errors on the console log but still doesnt show/hide the header? this is the script already loading in my header? <script type="text/javascript" src="http://testsiteclash.co.uk/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1"></script> this is loading before the header div in my <head>

Comment: Ahh, I changed your code a bit just for testing. You need to use `jQuery(document).scroll(function($){` and it should work. Observe the $ between the (). Also, if you run the snippet from my answer you can see that is working.

Comment: @lonut have edited snippet to the exact js in my file and it is still not working? So confused?!

Comment: Do you have jquery library included?

Comment: Also, please do not update your question with the code from my answer.